# How to do a .where(somecolumn == None/Null/Empty) with Peewee?

Tags: python, sql, orm, flask, peewee

I'm using peewee in my Flask application and I have one column in a table which can be null:

```
somecolumn = ForeignKeyField(Something, related_name='messages', null = True, default=None)
```

I now want to select all records in which somecolumn is not null/None/Empty. I tried to do this with the following:

```
Message.select().where(Message.somecolumn != None)
Message.select().where(Message.somecolumn != '')
```

Unfortunately, neither works. Does anybody know how I can do this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not a peewee expert, but from the documentation ([Querying](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#where-clause)) it looks like you need:

```
Message.select().where(Message.somecolumn >> None)
```

Answer (score 9):

It's a possibility:

```
Message.select().where(Message.somecolumn.is_null(False))
```

[Documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html?highlight=is_null)